# Proper way to build time series dataset

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, dataset

I have daily time series but need to predict weekly total.
Here is example:

|  | date | col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | -1.021 | 0.708 | -0.564 | -0.502 | 0.244 | -106.538 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | -1.226 | -1.464 | 1.047 | 1.574 | 0.224 | -42.152 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | -0.156 | 1.168 | 0.338 | 0.087 | 0.254 | 72.307 |
| 3 | 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | -0.083 | -1.505 | 0.082 | -1.406 | 0.76 | -65.941 |
| 4 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.712 | -1.372 | 1.471 | -0.173 | -1.614 | 37.075 |
| 5 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | -0.897 | 0.076 | 0.975 | -0.012 | -0.677 | -65.985 |
| 6 | 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | -0.559 | 0.377 | -0.066 | -1.523 | 1.566 | 44.787 |
| 7 | 2023-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.629 | -1.38 | -0.056 | 0.074 | -1.703 | -133.008 |
| 8 | 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 0.856 | 0.214 | 0.173 | -0.447 | -1.246 | 0.211 |
| 9 | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 1.073 | -0.365 | -1.045 | 0.538 | -0.839 | -98.987 |
| 10 | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | -0.86 | -0.385 | -0.577 | 0.047 | 1.006 | -99.636 |
| 11 | 2023-01-12 00:00:00 | -1.713 | 1.354 | 1.238 | -0.469 | -0.115 | 54.005 |
| 12 | 2023-01-13 00:00:00 | 1.551 | -0.998 | -0.214 | 0.234 | 0.984 | 68.9 |
| 13 | 2023-01-14 00:00:00 | -0.319 | -0.796 | 0.021 | -0.752 | 1.076 | -22.462 |
| 14 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | -0.592 | -0.864 | -0.831 | -0.487 | 0.049 | -102.358 |

The basic approaches are sum days predict in week or group and predict weekly.
The idea is to extend training data to predict weeks using slide window of 7 days to group data so first row is sum of 2023-01-01 - 2023-01-07 days, second row is sum of 2023-01-02 - 2023-01-08 days etc. This method gives much more samples for training model.
I am not sure whether it is theoretically correct due to strong autocorrelation or something else.
Moreover, I need to predict strictly Mon-Sun target sum on inference.

Comment: What specifically is the question?

Comment: @JonNordby Is it correct to aggregate data in such way to train model or it breaks structure of data?